# Почему мьютекс доступен в теле лямбда-выражения, если его никто явно не захватил?

Tags: c++, c++11

Я представлю фрагмент кода, где явно используется мьютекс внутри лямбда-выражения.
При этом, он, мьютекс, не захватывается, а остаётся доступен, что и вызвало интерес.

```
class session {
private: 
    void do_read() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(data_),
            [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex>g(mtx);
                //...
            });
    }
    
    // One mutex for all sessions
    static std::mutex mtx;
};
```

Почему у программиста есть право явно использовать не захваченный мьютекс в теле лямбда-выражения?

Comment: Почему только он?.. Все члены доступны.

Comment: Потому что единственный мьютекс в этом примере - статическое поле.

Comment: Глобальные и статические переменные не нуждаются в захвате.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, возможно Вы и можете подкрепить свои слова ссылкой на Стандарт, но даже если это и так, то интуитивно мне понять такое решение очень трудно.

Comment: Не вижу смысла искать ссылку, это легко проверить и объяснить на пальцах. Локальные переменные не имеют постоянного адреса в памяти, и их может быть не 1 штука (0 после выхода из функции, >1 при рекурсии, причем разные копии лямбды могут ссылаться на разные воплощения переменной). Поэтому лямбде, чтобы найти нужную локальную переменную, нужно запоминать ее адрес или копию - это и есть захват. А глобальные переменные существуют в единственном экземпляре, и адрес всегда одинаковый.

Comment: захват `[this,` разрешает доступ лямбде ко всем переменным класса, статические они или нет.

Comment: Поточнее вопрос задайте, а то никто ничего не понимает. Что такое у вас "захват" мютекса? Блокировка замка или использование в функции `do_read`? Что такое остаётся доступен? Нет блокировки замка или вы пытались получить к нему доступ из `main`?